# CO : CO₂ ratio when given amounts of carbon and oxygen react with each other

Tags: physical-chemistry

> By the reaction of carbon and oxygen a mixture of $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{CO2}$ is obtained. What is the composition of the mixture by mass obtained when 20 grams of $\ce{O2}$ reacts with 12 grams of carbon?

I wrote the equation as

$$\ce{4C + 3O2 -> 2CO + 2CO2}$$

and identified $\ce{O2}$ as the limiting reagent then the masses of $\ce{CO}$ formed will be 11.66 grams and mass of $\ce{CO2}$ formed will be 18.33 grams, which gives the ratio as 7:11, but the answer is given as 21:11.

Can somebody please tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: What was your motivation for writing the equation that way?   That automatically assumes an (incorrect) answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost refer to the tip given in the answer of @ChesterMiller: use separate reactions for each given process, and don't rely on limiting reagent concept when more than one reaction is possible:

\begin{align}
\ce{\underset{$x$}{C} + 0.5 \underset{$0.5x$}{O2} &-> \underset{$x$}{CO}} \tag{1} \\
\ce{\underset{$y$}{C} + \underset{$y$}{O2} &-> \underset{$y$}{CO2}} \tag{2}
\end{align}

let $x$ mol be the amount of carbon participating in forming carbon monoxide $\ce{CO}$, and $y$ mol -- the amount of carbon participating in forming carbon dioxide $\ce{CO2}$.

We have the following amounts of reactants in the system:

$$n(\ce{C}) = \frac{m(\ce{C})}{M(\ce{C})} = \frac{\pu{12 g}}{\pu{12 g mol^-1}} = \pu{1 mol}$$

$$n(\ce{O2}) = \frac{m(\ce{O2})}{M(\ce{O2})} = \frac{\pu{20 g}}{\pu{32 g mol^-1}} = \pu{0.625 mol}$$

where $m$ -- mass; $M$ -- molecular weight.

Taking into account reactants ratios, the following system of equations is relevant:

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
x + y &= 1 \qquad &\text{total amount of carbon}\\
0.5x + y &= 0.625 \qquad &\text{total amount of oxygen}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Solving this system of equations, one gets $x = 0.75$ (mol) and $y = 0.25$ (mol). Hence the masses of the products are:

\begin{align}
m(\ce{CO}) &= x \cdot M(\ce{CO}) &= \pu{0.75 mol} \cdot \pu{28 g mol^-1} &= \pu{21 g} \\
m(\ce{CO2}) &= y \cdot M(\ce{CO2}) &= \pu{0.25 mol} \cdot \pu{44 g mol^-1} &= \pu{11 g}
\end{align}

Comment: Is this actually a plausible reaction?  Could we also get more $CO_2$ but some unburnt $C$?

Comment: @badjohn The way the problem is stated (conditions were such that only $\ce{CO}$ + $\ce{CO2}$ are presented in the system) suggests only this solution.

Comment: @andselisk Yes but it raised this related question in my mind.  Maybe, I should start a new question.

Answer (score 5):

You should have written:

$$\ce{C + O2 -> CO2}$$

and

$$\ce{C + \frac{1}{2}O2 -> CO}$$

Then you should have determined what fraction of the carbon reacts by by the first reaction and what fraction of the carbon reacts by the second reaction.

Comment: How can I find that?

Comment: Let f be fraction of C that forms CO2 and let (1-f) be the fraction of C that forms CO.  Solve for f such that 20 grams of O2 are consumed.